# substring_index skips delimiter from right

Tags: mysql, substring

I have a table 'car_purchases' with a 'description' column. The column is a string that includes first name initial followed by full stop, space and last name.
An example of the Description column is

> 'Car purchased by J. Blow'

I am using 'substring_index' function to extract the letter preceding the '.' in the column string. Like so:

```
SELECT
Description,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(Description, '.', 1) as TrimInitial,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(Description, '.', 1),' ', -1) as trimmed,
length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(Description, '.', 1),' ', -1)) as length
from car_purchases;
```

I will call this query 1.

[picture of the result set (Result 1) is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51uaH.png)

As you can see the problem is that the 'trimmed' column in the select statement starts counting the 2nd delimiter ' ' instead of the first from the right and produces the result 'by J' instead of just 'J'. Further the length column indicates that the string length is 5 instead of 4 so WTF?

However when I perform the following select statement;

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX('Car purchased by J. Blow', '.', 1),' ', -1); -- query 2
```

Result = 'J' as 'Result 2'.

As you can see from result 1 the string in column 'Description' is exactly (as far as I can tell) the same as the string from 'Result 2'. But when the substring_index is performed on the column (instead of just the string itself) the result ignores the first delimiter and selects a string from the 2nd delimiter from the right of the string.

I've racked my brains over this and have tried 'by ' and ' by' as delimiters but both options do not produce the desired result of a single character. I do not want to add further complexity to query 1 by using a trim function. I've also tried the cast function on result column 'trimmed' but still no success. I do not want to concat it either.

There is an anomaly in the 'length' column of query 1 where if I change the length function to char_length function like so:

```
select length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(Description, '.', 1),' ', -1)) as length -- result = 5

select char_length(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
SUBSTRING_INDEX(Description, '.', 1),' ', -1)) as length -- result = 4
```

Can anyone please explain to me why the above select statement would produce 2 different results? I think this is the reason why I am not getting my desired result.

But just to be clear my desired outcome is to get 'J' not 'by J'.

I guess I could try reverse but I dont think this is an acceptable compromise. Also I am not familiar with collation and charset principles except that I just use the defaults.

Cheers Players!!!!

Comment: Ok I have ID'ed what was causing the malfunction. I copied the data into column 'description' from excel spreadsheet into the query tab and inserted into table car_purchases. This produces the 'by J', where as if I just typed the string into the column then i get 'J' from query 1. I now suspect that it has something to do with the collation and/or character set of the copied string from excel.

Answer (score 0):

[`CHAR_LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) returns length in characters, so a string with 4 2-byte characters would return 4. [`LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_length) however returns length in bytes, so a string with 4 2-byte characters would return 8. The discrepancy in your results (including [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)) says that the "space" between `by` and `J` is not actually a single-byte space (ASCII 0x20) but a 2-byte character that looks like a space. To workaround this, you could try replacing all unicode characters with spaces using [`CONVERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) and [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace). In this example, I have an `en-space` unicode character in the string between `by` and `J`. The `CONVERT` changes that to a `?`, and the `REPLACE` then converts that to a space:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX("Car purchased by J. Blow", '.', 1),' ', -1)
```

Output:

```
by J
```

With `CONVERT` and `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(CONVERT("Car purchased by J. Blow" USING ASCII), '?', ' '), '.', 1),' ', -1)
```

Output

```
J
```

For your query, you would replace the string with your column name i.e.

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(CONVERT(description USING ASCII), '?', ' '), '.', 1),' ', -1)
```

[Demo on DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5877783677a96ca5823fac522c52dded)

Comment: Ok that works awesome. I did have to change the query around a bit to manipulate the column 'description' instead of the string 'Car purchased by J. Blow'. So the query reads; SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(CONVERT(description USING ASCII), '?', ' '), '.', 1),' ', -1);  I then updated the car_purchases table using;  update car_purchases as A set A.Description = 
replace(convert(A.Description using ASCII), '?', ' '); Thanks again!